# retain masonry effect with Angular JS sorting and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please take a look at the fiddle which has Angular JS with Jquery masonry layout. I want to use angular sorting and searching as well.
The transitions are not very smooth and also the masonry layout does not seem to be fully functional.

Is there a suggestion on how I can achieve a masonry type affect and include angular with sorting/filtering etc.
http://jsfiddle.net/rdikshit/AMbF5/embedded/result/

```
<div ng:app="test">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" /> <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'id'; reverse=!reverse">Order by id</a>
 <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'name';reverse=!reverse">Order by name</a>
 <a href="#" ng-click="order = 'age';reverse=!reverse">Order by age</a>
    <div id="container" masonry>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { name: nameFilter } | orderBy: order:reverse" class={{item.style}}> <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <br /<span>id: {{item.id}}</span>

            <br /> <span>Age: {{item.age}}</span>

            <br /> <span>Style: {{item.style}}</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Out

If there are any custom directives etc that will help me achieve this easily, please suggest. I tried Passy's directive however when I add the sorting and filtering to it, the masonry layout breaks.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact same problem. I was able to resolve it by setting a watch on the sorting variable(s) and then having masonry reload the items and re-trigger the layout method (on a slight delay) when the sort values were changed.

> ```
> $scope.$watch('order', function (newVal, oldVal) {
>     if (newVal != oldVal) {
>         $timeout(function () {
>             $element.masonry('reloadItems');
>             $element.masonry('layout');
>         }, 300);
>     }
> }, true);
> $scope.$watch('reverse', function (newVal, oldVal) {
>     if (newVal != oldVal) {
>         $timeout(function () {
>             $element.masonry('reloadItems');
>             $element.masonry('layout');
>         }, 300);
>     }
> }, true);
> ```