# Shuffle Animation for Angular on OrderBy

Tags: angularjs, animation, sql-order-by

Does anyone know of a sound solution for a shuffle animation when angular reorders items in ng-repeat. I've tried masonry ([retain masonry effect with Angular JS sorting and filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435675/retain-masonry-effect-with-angular-js-sorting-and-filtering)), ng-move, and various other solutions posted - none have worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: make a plunker of the code you have so far, that would help us understand what's going wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Masonry call is inside a custom directive you created, have a look at:

**How do I use animations in my own directives?**

> Animations within custom directives can also be established by
>   injecting $animate directly into your directive and making calls to it
>   when needed.

```
myModule.directive('my-directive', ['$animate', function($animate) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.on('click', function() {
    if(element.hasClass('clicked')) {
      $animate.removeClass(element, 'clicked');
    } else {
      $animate.addClass(element, 'clicked');
    }
  });
};
}]);
```

Check the API documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate